# I don't know what is the error in the sql syntax

Tags: c#, mysql

I am implementing a login form using C# and MySQL, The user should enter his/her username and password then select if he/she is a student, instructor or admin. 
then I want to check if entered values are correct , here is my code:

```
connection.Open();
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "Select * from @userType where username=@user and password=@pass";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userType", userType);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", user);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", pass);

cmd.Connection = connection;
MySqlDataReader login = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

But the query didn't work ! 
the error message :

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException,  HResult=0x80004005, 
>   Message=You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''student' where username='noor123' and password='123456'' at
>   line Source=MySql.Data

what is the error ?

Comment: You cant use parameters for the table name I believe

Comment: When I have a problem with a query, I print it in the standard output and I paste it in my SQL client. It's help a lot.

Comment: After you fix the problem with the parameter then you will have another syntax error  caused by the reserved keyword 'password'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL query generated by that code is:

```
Select * from 'student' where username="noor123" and password="123456"
```

The table can't be inside `''` as that's not correct SQL syntax.

You can't use the parameter for the table name, do this instead, this way you won't get `''` for the table name:

```
connection.Open();
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "Select * from " + userType.ToString() + " where username=@user and password=@pass";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", user);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", pass);

cmd.Connection = connection;
MySqlDataReader login = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: I don't think that this goes well with the syntax parser. Did you try it?

Comment: @Steve I was wrong it is `''` instead of `""`
Edit: Whoops I had typed userType.toString() inside the string, now it's out of it and concatenated.

Comment: Now you are missing spaces. And I hope that userType is not coming directly from the user input

Comment: Is it ok to put userType.toString() without concatenation (+) ?

Comment: @Noor Nope, I had typed it wrong, I've edited it, it should be fixed already.

Comment: `... "Select * from userType.toString() ...` won't work too. Then the literal `userType.toString()` is in the query. And it's `ToString()` with capital `T` in C#. Use `... $"Select * from { userType.ToString() } ...` or `... "Select * from " + userType.ToString() + "...`. The `ToString()` might also be superfluous depending on the type of `userType` which likely is a string already.

Comment: @stickybit Thanks, I hadn't noticed the spaces, I've already changed it, I've also fixed ToString(), I'm a java guy haha. ToString() might be unnecesary but I've included it just in case the userType is not a String.

Answer (score 0):

If this is just an assignment and not a real-world program then do the following.

1. Make sure variables userType, user and pass are of type String.
2. Make sure that userType represents a syntactically correct table or view name.
3. Update this line `cmd.CommandText = $"Select * from {userType} where username=@user and password=@pass";`
4. Remove this line `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userType", userType);`

I believe that should help. I didn't check myself.

However in real world you shouldn't program it this way. There are many security considerations when dealing with authentication/authorization not mentioning the possibility for sql injection. If this is a real project then I recommend you to read appropriate materials regarding the subject.